# Reading different values from same memory address

Tags: c, memory

I'm implementing karatsuba's multiplication algorithm in C and while debugging I found this error I can't explain:
In every step I split the numbers to multiply in halves, which I do by assigning the appropriate pointers to my data type. When I output my values I get this:

```
a->l: 8 a->u: 4 a->v: 0x51fc270 a: 4072
b->l: 8 b->u: 4 b->v: 0x51fc278 b: 6718
```

which turns into (for a)

```
a->l: 2 a->u: 2 a->v: 0x51fc272 a: 00
b->l: 2 b->u: 2 b->v: 0x51fc270 b: 00
```

and (for b)

```
a->l: 2 a->u: 2 a->v: 0x51fc27a a: 00
b->l: 2 b->u: 2 b->v: 0x51fc278 b: 00
```

There are no write accesses in between those two outputs and the first two structures always produce the same output.
Could anybody explain this behavior? Cause I am truly lost..

The structs holding the data look like this

```
struct mp_type
{
    int l, u; //length of v and places used (length of number stored)
    char* v; //array which stores the value (the number)
};
typedef struct mp_type mp_int;
```

the last value is the number stored in the array v.

```
// high has lower address as low order digits are stored at the end of the array
mp_int low1, low2, high1, high2;
high1.l = high1.u = a->u / 2;
low1.l = low1.u = a->u - high1.u;
low1.v = a->v + low1.u;
high1.v = a->v;
high2.l = high2.u = b->u / 2;
low2.l = low2.u = b->u - high2.u;
low2.v = (b->v + low2.u);
high2.v = b->v;
```

That's how I split the numbers. a->u and b->u are always even numbers.

Here[1](http://n.ethz.ch/~wiseveri/download/code.zip) you find a slimmer version of the project, that reproduces the error.

Comment: You will need to explain what your data structures look like and what all these values you printed mean. Also, show some code.

Comment: The values mean in order:
length of the array pointed to by v
number of digits the number stored has
The address of the first element of v
The number stored in the array between index a->l - a->u and a->l

Comment: @wiseveri this reminds me about how the `union` works, but I don't know what you are doing in practice, in theory that could be it http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Defining-Unions ( it a standard class type, nothing special about the GNU link )

Comment: @wiseveri you are aware that `l1.v = a->v + l1.u;` does pointer artihmetic, making `l1.v` point to the `l1.u`'th element in `a->v`, right? And that `h1.v = a->v;` is copying pointers and not the arrays themselves.

Comment: @Andrei: Yes I'm aware of that and that's what I want to do. I don't want to copy the values I just want to use only part of the whole number for further computations and copying would be way to expensive. Those values are always just read and never written to. That's way I can't explain to myself why I read different values from the same memory address.

Comment: @wiseveri then add a small program that reproduces the issue

Comment: @Andrei: I'm not sure I can. This issue occurs only with the result of a previous computation 3 levels down the recursion. But I'll try to make some small program up..

Comment: So, `u` is the length of the number in decimal representation and you store the numbers in `v` as decimal digits? What's your data format of this `v` array?

Comment: Yes the numbers are stored base 10 in v. v is an array of characters (char)

Comment: This is a good example of variable and field names that are too short and/or undocumented.  The `u` and `l` fields could certainly use more explanation as well as `l1`, `h1`, etc.   I noticed some explanation in the comments, but **please** edit the original post to provide this info.  It would save reviewers a lot of time and more likely generate your sought answer.

Comment: @chux: Added more comments and made some variable names more self explanatory (if you know the algorithm I guess)

Comment: If the code worked as you said (reading from same memory address without modifying it), it would produce the same results. Since it doesn't, there must be a bug somewhere. Without seeing the code, we can't tell you where it is.

Comment: @interjay: Added a link to the code at the bottom of the post

Comment: @wiseveri: You should consider rewriting your question. We don't know the algorithm - and we don't want to know. Try to construct a minimal example to reproduce the problem, most likely you will find the error in the process. If you don't find it, we can  then look at your memory access. But I don't want to download your whole project and debug it.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if u is even, but the assignment of `v` should be `low1.v = a->v + high1.u;` since it's after the high array.

Comment: I actually found my error today. It was a mere indexing error. The numbers in the example are stored in the array of length 8, but the numbers themselves are only 4 digits long. So they actually start at a->v + a->l - a->u. That's why I read wrong values as I start reading before the actual number.
Thanks for everybody's input!